# PostgreSQL, problems with Boolean type storing values as "T" and "F" breaking ORM

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, dapper

If I define a boolean data type in a Postgres table and query from it, the results for the boolean columns come back as "t" or "f".

I'm using NPGSQL as my driver and Dapper as a ORM. This causes a problem because Dapper is unable to convert "t" or "f" into a boolean value, and all boolean values end up as False.

Is there a way to change this behavior with Postgres, or do I need to hack around it by using a character data type?

Comment: Dapper needs values that the .NET Boolean type can handle (true/false), it wont work with "T/F/Yes/No/On/Off/0/1" etc.

Comment: That sounds like a bug (or misconfiguration) in the driver.  A proper driver should convert data values between the database types and the client language's types.

Comment: Peter, it is a bug in NPGSQL, I may patch it and see if they will take a submission, I kinda wish they had a github/bitbucket instead of a private CVS system :(

Comment: Hi, do you know where Dapper is getting the value from Npgsql which in turn is returning an incorrect value? If it is calling NpgsqlDataReader.GetValue(int) it should be getting a boolean value. If possible, would you mind to send us a testcase?  Our cvs code can be found at: cvs.npgsql.org. I hope it helps.

Comment: what npgsql version did you use when encountered this bug anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to integer to get 0 or 1

```
SELECT boolean_value::INT ;
```

or to varchar to get 'true' or 'false'.

```
SELECT boolean_value::VARCHAR ;
```

Most DB drivers should be able to handle the one or the other.

Comment: I didn't want to have to modify all of the queries to use casts, but if there is no way to change the default behavior this will have to do.

Comment: The boolean datatype in postgres is a bit sucky since it takes 1 byte of storage too, so in many cases I use char(1) status values instead of booleans since it's not that uncommon to need more values for variables that appear boolean at first design.